# REACT- DOM Mutation Warning Meaning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> [Violation] Added synchronous DOM mutation listener to a 'DOMNodeInserted' event. Consider using MutationObserver to make the page more responsive.

There's another question regarding this warning. I already answered a way to solve it there, and that is not the reason for this question. 
(for those who would like to know: this warning disappears if you add a setTimeOut function to your event handler, so it is not synchronous anymore)

The REAL question is: What does "DOM mutation listener" mean? Or what IS a "DOM mutation listener"? And what does it do? I asked my teacher, and not even him knew. He suggested it might be something now deprecated but I feel like it shows up for a reason and I would like to fully understand it in case i get a similar error but different regarding a "DOM mutation listener" in the future.

Answer (score 6):

A DOM mutation listener does just what it sounds like - it listens for mutations to the DOM. For example, if you attach such a listener, and then add or remove a node, the listener may be able to detect it and fire a callback. There are various types of DOM mutations that can be watched for.

For an example of a *synchronous* one (which are slow, deprecated, and not recommended):

```js
container.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', () => {
  console.log('mutation seen!');
});

container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'content');
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

For this sort of functionality, you're recommended to use MutationObserver instead, which is not quite synchronous - a MutationObserver callback runs during a *microtask* after the mutation:

```js
new MutationObserver(() => {
  console.log('mutation seen!');
}).observe(container, { childList: true });

container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'content');
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Mutation observers are *usually* only the right choice when you need to interact with the functionality of code you can't change - for example, if you're using a script or a library that changes something in the DOM, and you need to be able to detect when that change occurs, but you can't modify the source script *and* that script doesn't provide any externally-visible indication that such a change occurred.

Except in that (unusual) situation, there are usually better methods to react to changes, such as just calling a function after the function that changes the DOM is done.

Comment: So basically a "DOM mutation listener" is pretty much just any function that adds/creates or removes a DOM element? This type of warning never appeared with Vanilla Javascript.

Comment: Furthermore, what is "beforeend" for on the code you wrote?

Comment: No, a "DOM mutation listener" is something that *listens* to such an event. Something that actually adds or removes an element or otherwise mutates the DOM isn't a listener. The warning will only appear if you explicitly listen for one of the deprecated events (like `DOMNodeInserted`).

Comment: The `beforeend` is just a parameter that `insertAdjacentHTML` requires - it's not important. Any other method of adding a node to `container` would work too, like `createElement` and `appendChild`

Comment: oh, kk. So the "DOM mutation listener" is just a default mechanism that listens for the event of adding/removing a DOM element. Although, i did not use "DOMNodeInserted" at any moment. Could it be because i mixed the "document.createElement()" method from vanilla javascript to create an li inside of the React app then?

Comment: *Something* added the listener. If it wasn't you, then it must have come from somewhere in the React code, or from something it imported.