# Listener added for a synchronous 'DOMSubtreeModified' DOM Mutation Event using latest version of jQuery v3.7.1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get the following issue in the Edge console:

```
[Deprecation] Listener added for a synchronous 'DOMSubtreeModified' DOM Mutation Event. This event type is deprecated (https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#legacy-event-types) and work is underway to remove it from this browser. Usage of this event listener will cause performance issues today, and represents a risk of future incompatibility. Consider using MutationObserver instead.
```

I see other users are having the same issue with Chrome and Firefox.

This "error" is in the jQuery code, not my script.  How am I supposed to fix this?  I am concerned that my code will not run in future browser versions.  Can I safely assume that at some point jQuery will be updated to resolve this issue or am I on my own here?  I can find no information on Jquery.com or elsewhere that tells me how to resolve/fix this. An there are no support on Jquery.com other than forums.  I see some folks have posted code that supposedly fixes the issue but no information on exactly where I need to add that code.  Do I add it to the Jquery code file?  And if so, where?  I'm using jquery-3.7.1.min.js, the error is marked on a specific line in the file.

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning. Ignore it, and expect that a future version of jQuery will fix the problem.

Comment: If people have posted patches, they probably refer to the non-minified version of the library.

Comment: Do you have a link to one of these fixes?

Comment: @Barmar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59699852/react-dom-mutation-warning-meaning

Comment: That's ReactJS, not jQuery.

Comment: I looked in the source code for jQuery, it doesn't have this event anywhere. So it's probably coming from another library that uses jQuery to create event listeners. You'll need to look at the stack trace to see what's calling it.

Comment: "*my code will not run in future browser versions*" that's generally what deprecated means.  Though equally as generally, these things take some time to get removed.